# Merging a Branch on Git Basic Questions

Tags: git, git-branch

This is a very beginner question on Git. I am following along the book [here](https://happygitwithr.com/git-branches.html) and website [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging) with respect to branching and merging.

I have a readme file on github that I pull onto my local machine where i create a branch, update the readme file and attempt to merge it back to the main/origin. I cant seem to get the last step right and i would appreciate any pointers.

```
$ git add README.md

# Creates a commit
$ git commit -m 'first commit of the day'

# Pushes the commit to github - no issues
$ git push

# Create and checkout a branch called issue-1
$ git branch issue-1
$ git checkout issue-1
```

Its at this point i update the readme file with an additional line of text, something like "hello world"

```
# Assume I am still on the branch, I commit my changes
$ git commit --all -m "Completed issue; issue 1 closed"

# Now i check out the main portion of my project that i want to merge my
# changes into and I merge this into my main project origin.
$ git checkout origin

# Note: switching to 'origin'.

# You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
# changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in 
# this state without impacting any branch.....

$ git merge issue-1

# Updating 0ad9cb3..8f0455d
# Fast-forward
 # README.md | 1 +
 # 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
```

This doesn't actually merge my changes into the main project. If i attempt to push it back to github:

```
$ git push
# fatal: You are not currently on a branch.
# To push the history leading to the current (detached HEAD)
# state now, use
    git push origin HEAD:<name-of-remote-branch>
```

Comment: `origin` is an alias for a remote, and not the name of a branch. You should probably be using `git checkout main` or `git switch -`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to go back from branch `issue-1` to `master` or `main`.

You should do `git checkout master` or `git checkout main` instead of `git checkout origin`.

`origin` is the name of the remote (which is GitHub in your case). Not the name of a branch.

Comment: Thank you both `thchp` and `Richard Smith`. Both of these answers were exactly what i was looking for